# Dialing a SIP number with TWINKLE client, from Ubuntu Linux Terminal. Is it possible?

Tags: sip, voip, ubuntu-10.04, i386

I am having a number of portable touchscreen computers with Ubuntu Linux 10.04LTS Lucid Lynx, the processor architecture is "i386". I used TWINKLE VOIP client and through SIP i am able to call to those units from IP Phone and similarly i am also able to call the IP phone from the Touchscreen computers as well.

The problem is-- I need a keyboard every-time i need to dial a number. There is no onscreen keyboard feature.

Is it possible to dial a sip number directly from the Linux terminal?

If it is possible then i will incorporate the script within a small GUI application, so that the user will call numbers with my GUI application's touch interface.

Comment: Did you try to google "twinkle command line"? I did: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/twinkle.1.html

Comment: thank you, i will try and do the same..

Comment: OK. I have written my suggestion up as an answer in expectation this works for you

Comment: heyyy it actually worked.. thanx a lot man :)
i used--
sudo twinkle --immediate --call <number>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out the man page for twinkle ( `man twinkle` ), online version http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/twinkle.1.html you will see that there is both an option to specify the called party from the command line, and also a CLI interface

When you run twinkle, you can add `-call` to dial a number.

By contrast `-c` starts a CLI interface (presumably with options for dialling numbers, answering etc, but I don't have it on this machine).

Another useful switch is `-cmd` which lets you add a series of CLI commands to run. These can be used for instance to answer an incoming call.